# How can I connect to a website with different IP Address?

Tags: java, ip, ip-address

I want to perform load tests on my website, so I need a way to connect to the website using dynamically different ip Addresses. is There a possible way to do this in java or C++?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? This question is very very vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host needs to know about these addresses before you can use them. You can add many virtual addresses to the same network adapter.  When you create a socket you can specify a source address.  You can do this in Java or C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect from different addresses you have two choices, be on that address when you connect or connect through a proxy.  The second option is your best, you'll just need to find a proxy (or proxies) through which you can connect.